# Is it possible to set PATH on Mac OS X Lion without restarting?

Tags: macos, path, operating-systems, osx-lion

Is there a way to set the `PATH` on `/etc/paths` without the need to reboot your Mac? I know I can do it using an alias but it's not permanent.

For example, I want to set the `PATH` for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want the PATH variable to be set in your terminal environment. If you are using bash (default on Mac OS X) you can add

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/your/path/to/mysql
```

to your `.bashrc` file in the home directory

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update the system-wide path.

You can execute the line specified by @Matteo though (without needing to add to `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile`) and then launch all applications from Terminal. They will inherit the modified `$PATH` value.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you set the path in /etc/bashrc?  Seems like this would be system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way to edit PATH env variable for Terminal mode:

(This is just a different way to do what is mentioned above in case you don't have R/W permission, as I did not)

Navigate to the /private/etc/paths in Finder, r-click, Get Info, Select Sharing & Permissions, change Everyone to Read & Write, edit and save the file (append the new path to the end of the list), then restore the permissions if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

After you set the `PATH`, in a Terminal window you can just type `source ~/.bash_profile` and hit enter. To verify that your `PATH` is updated, just execute `echo $PATH`.